# After migrating to react native to 0.59.8, iOS app is sluggish,laggy

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have migrated 'ios-native' + 'react-native' to react 0.59.8. I had a stable version before migrating to 0.59.8 version of react. After migration, it's very laggy &  slow.
Most changes are in imports(99%), no other specif changes were required to make application running.

I had profiled application and found that leak with react view becomingFirstResponser. As attached below screen shot.

[image]

Note: This leak was present in the previous version also. Whereas works fine on android.

Anyone who has faced a similar problem after the update.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which version of react native did you upgrade from?

Comment: @kenmistrry from 0.52

Comment: @the1pawan : I have just updated my react-native project with version 0.60.3 and application is working as it was before. My guess is, you have some plugin which messing up things for you. This updates of react-native seem like a major one. Many plugins still have not adapted for this. So cross-check your plugins once.

Comment: @the1pawan, If you have upgraded some days ago, you can still think off another v upgrade to a major release 0.60. You can check about the same https://medium.com/@shashankm.malviya/react-native-0-60-c38acf222d4a. Even this is also available on current react native website. Please ask me if you stuck up somewhere. I have done a successfull migration to v 0.6.